# Using "ä", "ö" and "ü" with glossaries-Package

Tags: symbols, glossaries, xindy

I am trying to write my 'Matura work' for school in LaTeX. Therefore I am using MacTeX and Texshop and normally it works pretty fine.

But at the moment I have some trouble with a glossary entry:

```
\newglossaryentry{gloss:iosgerät}{name={\emph{iOS-Gerät}},description={iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad und Apple TV werden mit iOS betrieben. In dieser Arbeit wird Apple TV jedoch nicht gemeint, wenn von iOS-Geräten die Rede ist.}}
```

Picture of console-output:

[image: http://db.tt/LmapdUYH]

Some days ago I read that Xindy can help to fix issues like this but I have no Idea how to use Xindy instead of MakeIndex.

I should have a engine like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
bfname=$(dirname "$1")/"`basename "$1" .tex`"
makeindex -s "$bfname".ist -t "$bfname".alg -o "$bfname".acr "$bfname".acn
makeindex -s "$bfname".ist -o "$bfname".gls -t "$bfname".glg "$bfname".glo
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 7):

The first argument of `\newglossaryentry` is just a symbolic name; in these, as in the argument to `\label`, no accented letter should be used.

Use

```
\newglossaryentry{gloss:iosgerat}{
  name={\emph{iOS-Gerät}},
  description={iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad und Apple TV werden
               mit iOS betrieben. In dieser Arbeit wird Apple
               TV jedoch nicht gemeint, wenn von iOS-Geräten
               die Rede ist.}
}
```

That key will never appear in your document and is used only for internal references.

Comment: I think `name=\emph{iOS-Gerät}` should be avoided because `glossaries` has keys to format the name.

Comment: It'd be customary in German to replace the umlaut <ä> by <ae>. Counterintuitive as it may be, the dots of an umlaut can't really be considered accents and hence just left out; <ä>, <ö> and <ü> pretty much are letters of their own. (Just like a sharp s <ß> usually would be replaced by a double s when not available, not by a single s.)

Comment: @doncherry It was just to remark that the key is an arbitrary string of (7 bit, printable) ASCII characters; one can choose whatever string is deemed memorizable.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I just thought I'd share the extra information. It was on my mind because I'm contemplating whether an [tag:umlaut] tag would make sense.

Comment: Finnish has <å>, <ä> and <ö> after <z>.

Comment: @Oni You need to tell `glossaries` to use Xindy rather than MakeIndex, with appropriate collation options.

Comment: ```xindy: Cannot locate xindy modules directory at /usr/bin/xindy ``` but all the modules are in ```/usr/share/texmf-dist/xindy/modules/```.